# iAd Won't Load Test Ads

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, iad

iAd simply won't load the test ads and it's driving me insane. It just shows a white box and doesn't do any callbacks. This is all my code:

```
import UIKit
import iAd

class ViewController: UIViewController, ADBannerViewDelegate {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    self.canDisplayBannerAds = true

    let adBanner = ADBannerView()
    adBanner.delegate = self
    self.view.addSubview(adBanner)

    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```

Comment: Had you call delegate method in `ADBannerViewDelegate` ?

Comment: I'm Sorry? I actually got this particular app to work, however my original problem which then lead to this still doesn't work... please reference my other question

Comment: I mean that all the code? Had you implement the delegate method in `ADBannerViewDelegate` defined?

Comment: I'm sorry I still don't understand what you're asking?

Answer (score 1):

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, ADBannerViewDelegate {
  var adBannerView : ADBannerView

  override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

      self.canDisplayBannerAds = true

      adBannerView = ADBannerView(frame: self.view.bounds)
      adBannerView.center = CGPoint(x: adBannerView.center.x, y: view.bounds.size.height - adBannerView.frame.size.height / 2)
      adBannerView.delegate = self
      adBannerView.hidden = true
      self.view.addSubview(adBannerView)
  }

  func bannerView(banner: ADBannerView!, didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: NSError!) {
      //handle fail issue
      bannerView.hidden = true
  }

  func bannerViewDidLoadAd(banner: ADBannerView!) {
      bannerView.hidden = false 
  }
}
```